# Python dataframe remove top n rows and moveup remaining

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame of 2500 rows. I am trying to remove top n rows and move up remaining without changing the index. I am giving an example of my problem and what I wanted

```
df = 
      A
10    10.5
11    20.5
12    30.5
13    40.5
14    50.5
15    60.5
16    70.5
```

In the above, I would like to remove top two rows and moveup the remaining without disturbing the index. My code and present output:

```
idx = df.index
df.drop(df.index[:2],inplace=True)
df.set_index(idx[:len(df)],inplace=True)
df = 
      A
10    30.5
11    40.5
12    50.5
13    60.5
14    70.5
```

I got the output that I wanted. Is there a better way to do it? Like, oneline code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` to remove the rows and set the index to the original without the last 2 values.

```
df = df.iloc[2:].set_index(df.index[:-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.A.shift(-2).dropna(how='all'))
```

You can also use shift() to delete the resulting Na line to create a data frame.